# derivative of $\ln(4)$

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

what is the derivative of $\ln(4)$?

I am trying to find the derivative of this equation:
$h(x)=\ln(\frac{x^3\cdot e^x}{4})$

by rules of logs I simplified the $h(x)$ to the following: $h(x)=3\ln(x)+x-\ln(4)$

now when I try to find the derivative of that

$h'(x)=3\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(\ln(x))+\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(x)- \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(\ln(4))$

I get this:

$h'(x)=\frac{3}{x} +1 -\frac{1}{4}$

but my TI-89 tells me that the derivative of $h(x)$ is $h'(x)=\frac{3}{x} +1$

Now, does it mean that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(\ln(4)) =0$? or I did something wrong?

Comment: the derivative of a constant is 0

Comment: The derivative of a *constant* is always zero, so in particular the derivative of $\ln(4)$ is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the rule for derivatives of $\ln$:  $$\frac {d}{dx} \ln(f(x)) = \frac {\frac {d}{dx}f(x)}{f(x)}$$  In your case $f(x)=4$, thus $$\frac {d}{dx} \ln(4) = \frac {\frac {d}{dx} 4}{4} = \frac {0}{4} = 0$$

Comment: thank you for clear explanation

Comment: No problem. :-)

Comment: The chain rule? Are you sure?

Comment: @egreg What's wrong with the chain rule?

Comment: $\log 4$ is a constant to begin with.

Comment: @egreg I know.  But that doesn't mean the chain rule doesn't still work.  I've found that sometimes calculus $1$ students have a hard time understanding that the logarithm or exponential of a constant is constant, but since Tim had already answered as such, I decided to go the other route -- just use the chain rule for $\ln(f(x))$ and then show OP what that implies when $f(x)$ is a constant function -- which apparently made some sense to OP.

Answer (score 6):

No, you haven't done anything wrong.  $\ln 4$ is a constant.  Hence its derivative is $0$.